# Polynomials basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let we have a space of polynomials of degree $n$, then let us take the subspaces – even and odd polynomials, and my goal is to deduce and compare bases of such subspaces.

I suppose, that there is not any intersection of these subspaces’ bases since if for example we add an odd member to the even basis it will no longer be a basis for a subspaces of even polynomials:

$\mathcal{B}_{odd}=\{x,x^3,\dots , x^{2k+1}\}$, $\mathcal{B}_{even}=\{1,x^2,\dots , x^{2k}\}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is basis.

Am I right or I miss something?

Grazie!

Comment: If $B$ is a basis of a vector space $V$ and $v\in V\setminus B$, then $B\cup\{v\}$ is not a basis of $V$.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because in the exercise was written “find the bases and find the intersection of them”

Comment: To emphasize... the only polynomial which is simultaneously an even function and an odd function is $f(x)=0$.  Also to emphasize, there are infinitely many possible bases available for the spaces you describe.. for instance, $\{1,1+x^2,1+x^2+x^4,1+x^2+x^4+x^6,\dots\}$ is also a perfectly acceptable basis for $\mathcal{B}_{even}$, but regardless which bases were used here since each basis vector is an element of their corresponding vector space and the only vector present in both spaces is the zero vector, and the zero vector can not be used as a basis vector there can't possibly be any overlap